# what does 25% color mean ? how to convert it to hex value?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, colors

i got this from designer

```
25% white
39% black
```

i need to use color in ARGB
how do i convert that to hex?
please show detail math steps please

thanks

Comment: not sure why the thumbs down, serious about this quesiton i am not trolling

Comment: It's a simple ratio: `25:100 = x:y` Where `x` is the answer you seek and `y` is the maximum color value in your color model. (256 if you're using 8-bits for each channel.) 39% black = 61% white.

Comment: the downvotes are because it is not a good question and the tags are definitely inappropriate.

Comment: Ask the designer what that means. CMYK colors for example can amount to more than 100% and 25% white could be anything from a light gray to adding 25% translucent pure white to another color.

Comment: This is an odd request from a web designer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each color channel is represented by a byte (ranging from 0x0 to 0xFF in hex), so you have 4 channels: A (alpha), R (red), G (green), B (blue). Then, 0% means 0x0 and 100% means 0xFF, so:

0.25 * 255 = 64 in decimal = 40 in hex.
0.39 * 255 = 99 in decimal = 63 in hex.

```
                              AARRGGBB
White with 100% of opacity: 0xFFFFFFFF
White with  25% of opacity: 0x40FFFFFF
Black with 100% of opacity: 0xFF000000
Black with  39% of opacity: 0x63000000
```

Comment: When you say black = #000000, you're not taking into account the alpha channel, since this color is represented in RGB, not ARGB. RGB assumes that alpha is always 100%. In order to convert RGB to ARGB, just add the alpha channel at the left, so you'll have #40000000 (A = 25%, R = 0%, G  = 0%, B = 0%).